# Django - syncdb: table has more than one primary key

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to add my model to my database however am unsure why I am getting the following error.

"sqlite3.OperationalError: table "device_registration_device" has more than one primary key"

My model is

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Device(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    device_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I thought I only have one primary_key specified here (device_key)?

[EDIT] Ok, I think this may have something to do with the fact I am trying to use a serializer with this model..?

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('device_key')
```

Comment: Which version of django do you use?  In 1.7 this model work just fine.

Comment: have you previously run ``syncdb`` then added your ``device_key`` column and now you`re running syncdb again without deleting your db?

Comment: No I have flushed the entire database and then run syncdb. I am running Django 1.7

Comment: All django models have an explicit primary key that is automatically added by the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`primary_key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) documentation:

> `primary_key`
>
> `Field.primary_key` If `True`, this field is the primary key for the
>   model.
>
> **If you don’t specify `primary_key=True` for any field in your model,
>   Django will automatically add an `AutoField` to hold the primary key**, so
>   you don’t need to set `primary_key=True` on any of your fields unless
>   you want to override the default primary-key behavior. For more, see
>   Automatic primary key fields.
>
> `primary_key=True` implies `null=False` and `unique=True`. **Only one primary
>   key is allowed on an object.**

One reason you would get this error is if you first created the model (and migration), applied the migration with the default primary key added by django.

Next, you decided to set a different field as the primary key, and create the migration and now when you are trying to apply it, you are receiving this error.

It does not have to do with serialization as the error is at the database level.

You have a few ways to solve this problem:

1. Delete (or manually adjust) your migrations so that there is only one primary key for your model.
2. Keep the default primary key, and add change `device_key` to enforce unique-ness and (optionally) create an index on it:

   ```
   device_key = models.CharField(max_length=32,
                                 unique=True, null=False, db_index=True)
   ```

Comment: I have completed deleted my database on my file system and then re-run 'syncdb' / 'migrations' and I get the same error still.

Comment: That's because your migrations are re-doing the same error (that first they are creating the default primary key, and then trying to add your second primary key).

Comment: Thanks, all I needed to do was delete the migrations folder for my device_registration app.